# RTE editor for TYPO3

Tags: typo3, rte

I am searching an alternative to TYPO3's own RTE editor, I need something more flexibel and user friendly, in the best case something similar to the one used by Wordpress.
What I aim for exactly is to offer in BackEdn edition tasks a high flexibility with images and text alligns (there why I compare with Wordpress).
I have found some commercial solutions which are a bit to expensive and was trying to look for some open-source solution, none of the found in the Extension Repository seem to fit my purpose.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

rtehtmlarea (builtin) is the most flexible, trust on me. That's the reason why it cannot be replaced easily, as maintaining backwards compatibility with all customizations is impossible to achieve.

What did you search for in in TER? Not for tinymce probably. There are a few extensions bringing tinymce to TYPO3. Use [tinymce_rte](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tinymce_rte/current/), it's by far the best one (feature-rich, very compatible to TYPO3 and actively maintained by a team).